# spacing between words differs sometimes in tables and biblography

Tags: tables, bibliographies

I didn't change the default settings but the space between words is not the same everywhere in the document.
I don't really know why Latex is doing this but sometimes it just stretches the space between the words.
Like this:
[image]

It's a snippet from one of my tables.
Or in the Biblography:
[image]

[28] is normal and [29] is the anomaly...
I hope someone has an idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you use a `p` type column in the table?  If so, the text inside of it  is justified automatically. With narrow column widths and short texts, this can lead to quite large white spaces such as the ones you observe. To overcome this and to switch to left alignment, you can use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{...}` instead of `p{...}`. Regarding the bibliography: This is also caused by the text being justified in combination with latex not being able to find a better line breaking point in the url. You could try the `xurl` package.

Comment: @leandriis thank you so much you solved all my problems in a few seconds!!

Comment: Add to @leandriis comment, which should be put into an answer, `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` (before loading hyperref); presuming the `\url` command is used.

Comment: Although some tools as  `microtype` and `\emergencystretch` can help at some extent in these situations, one must be aware that  justify narrow texts  means be prepared to place  automatic and manual  hyphens everywhere or allow a very bad spacing. This is always true, but more true in technical texts were long words are very common. A text about internet in German in tables should be like the perfect storm  in this sense.